# Value of a polynomial with complex coefficients

Tags: proof-verification, polynomials, complex-numbers

Problem: let $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ be a root of polynomial $$p(x)=x^7-4x^5+3x^2+2x+1-2i$$ What is the value $p(\overline{\alpha})?$

Attempt: by hypothesis $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ is a root of $p(x)$ hence $p(\alpha)=0$. My aim is to find the value of $p(\overline{\alpha})$.

Let $\alpha=\rho(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))$ with $\rho>0\wedge -\pi<\theta\le\pi$, then $\overline{\alpha}=\rho(\cos(\theta)-i\sin(\theta))$.

I evaluate the polynomial in $\alpha$

$p(\alpha)=1+2\rho\cos(\theta)+3\rho^2\cos(2\theta)+4\rho^5\cos(5\theta)+\rho^7\cos(7\theta)+i(-2+2\rho\sin(\theta)+3\rho^2\sin(2\theta)-4\rho^5\sin(5\theta)+\rho^7\sin(7\theta))$

and in $\overline{\alpha}$

$p(\overline{\alpha})=1+2\rho\cos(\theta)+3\rho^2\cos(2\theta)-4\rho^5\cos(5\theta)+\rho^7\cos(7\theta)+i(-2-2\rho\sin(\theta)-3\rho^2\sin(2\theta)-4\rho^5\sin(5\theta)-\rho^7\sin(7\theta))$

Now $$\Im(p(\alpha)+p(\overline{\alpha}))=-4=\Im(p(\overline{\alpha}))$$ because $p(\alpha)=0$. On the other hand $$\Re(p(\alpha)-p(\overline{\alpha}))=0=\Re(p(\overline{\alpha}))$$ hence $p(\overline{\alpha})=\Re(p(\overline{\alpha}))+i\Im(p(\overline{\alpha}))=0-4i$.

Is this solution correct? Is there a way to solve the problem without all these calculations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $$\overline{p}(x) = \overline{p(\overline{x})} = x^7 -4x^5+3x^2+2x+1+2i=p(x)+4i . $$ Now 
$$ p(\alpha)=0 \Leftrightarrow 0=\overline{p(\alpha)} = \overline{p} (\overline{\alpha}) = p(\overline{\alpha}) + 4 i  $$

Comment: You are my god. Brilliant solution! Thanks!